# knockout.js visible binding to table cell contents not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, toggle

I'm using knockout.js (v2.2.1) for the first time, and am trying to build a table where elements toggle between text and input fields based on an "IsReadOnly" property in the view model.  This is accomplished using "visible" on span and input tags within the table cells.

Here's the table:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
     <button id="btnEditSave" data-bind="text: btnEditSave, click: doEditSave" style="float:right;" />
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Server Name: </td>
  <td>
   <span data-bind="text: Server.ServerName, visible: IsReadOnly() == true" />
   <input data-bind="value: Server.ServerName, visible: IsReadOnly() == false" maxlength="50" style="width:400px;" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and the model:

```
var ServerViewModel = function () {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.IsReadOnly = ko.observable(true);       // the form's input mode
    self.btnEditSave = ko.observable("Edit");    // the Edit/Save button text
    self.Server = ko.observable({});             // the Server object

    // Operations
    self.doEditSave = function () {
        var flag = self.IsReadOnly();
        if (flag) {
            // switch to Edit mode
            self.btnEditSave("Save");
            self.IsReadOnly(false);
        }
        else {
            // will eventually save the form data here...

            // switch back to readOnly
            self.btnEditSave("Edit");
            self.IsReadOnly(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything toggles as expected, except that the input field is not displayed.  I've tried various forms of the input tag's "visible" expression, yet nothing works.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should write `...value: Server().ServerName,...` and `...text: Server().ServerName,...` as `Server` is an `observable`.

Everything else seems pretty right to me.

BTW: A [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would help alot.

### EDIT:

I just set up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRShn/1/

The problem is that you write a ***self-closing* span** - which ***cannot* be selfclosing**. Just `write <span ...></span>` instead of `<span ... />` and **your initial version works**!

Comment: thanks for the tip, however using Server() gives the javascript error "Message: TypeError: Server is not a function;".

Comment: omg, figures it would be something like that -- re: should not use a self-closing span.  I've given you credit for the answer.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't determine why my first example didn't work, but I did find a solution:  use another property "IsEditable" which is the opposite of "IsReadOnly" so my expressions only test for true.

The table row is now:

```
<tr>
  <td>Server Name: </td>
  <td>
   <input data-bind="value: Server.ServerName, visible: IsEditable" maxlength="50" style="width:400px;" />
   <span data-bind="text: Server.ServerName, visible: IsReadOnly" />
  </td>
 </tr>
```

and the model is:

```
var ServerViewModel = function () {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.IsReadOnly = ko.observable(true);       // the form's input mode
    self.IsEditable = ko.observable(false);      // <<--- the workaround
    self.btnEditSave = ko.observable("Edit");    // the Edit/Save button text
    self.Server = ko.observable({});             // the Server object

    // Operations
    self.doEditSave = function () {
        var flag = self.IsReadOnly();
        if (flag) {
            // switch to Edit mode
            self.btnEditSave("Save");
            self.IsReadOnly(false);
            self.IsEditable(true);
        }
        else {
            // switch back to readOnly
            self.btnEditSave("Edit");
            self.IsReadOnly(true);
            self.IsEditable(false);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. But, if you ever really needed this, it would make sense to make `IsEditable` a computed property that just returns `!IsReadOnly()` since then you'll avoid having to try and keep them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 <span data-bind="text: Server.ServerName, visible: IsReadOnly"></span>
 <input data-bind="value: Server.ServerName, visible: !IsReadOnly()" maxlength="50" style="width:400px;" />
```

Edit: good catch by Warappa on the self-closing span. Knockout don't like 'em.

Comment: I had tried that, probably didn't work because of the self-closing span issue.